# Re- inject variable argument lists C lang

Tags: c, compilation, variadic-functions

I try to re-inject variable arg throw function :

```
#include < stdio.h >

  int test_va_arg(char * fmt, ...) {
    int c;

    c = printf(fmt);

    return (c);
  }

int test_va_arg2(char * fmt, ...) {
  int c;
  char buf[1024];

  sprintf(buf, "ADD->%s", fmt);
  c = printf(buf);

  return (c);
}

int test_va_arg3(char * fmt, ...) {
  int c;
  char * buf;

  buf = malloc(1024);
  sprintf(buf, "ADD->%s", fmt);
  c = printf(buf);

  return (c);
}

int main(void) {
  int c;

  c = test_va_arg("test_va_arg : %d %d %d\n", 421, 847, 1003);
  printf("test_va_arg2 :%d\n", c);
  c = test_va_arg2("test_va_arg2 : %d %d %d\n", 421, 847, 1003);
  printf("test_va_arg2 :%d\n", c);
  c = test_va_arg3("test_va_arg3 : %d %d %d\n", 421, 847, 1003);
  printf("test_va_arg2 :%d\n", c);
  c = test_va_arg("test_va_arg : %d %d %d\n", 421, 847, 1003);
  printf("test_va_arg2 :%d\n", c);
  return (0);
}
```

Output is

```
# ./test_va_arg 
test_va_arg : 421 847 1003
test_va_arg2 :27
ADD->test_va_arg2 : 4196615 178862877 2147483618
test_va_arg2 :49
ADD->test_va_arg3 : 4196615 13586477 2147483618
test_va_arg2 :48
test_va_arg : 421 847 1003
test_va_arg2 :27
```

I do not understand with the argument are not on the stack.
It seems to be link with the local variable. I think I must move the stack pointer but I do not know how to do it.

Comment: You are passing variable arguments to functions but you are not popping them before to call printf... Take a look [at this guide](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_macro_va_start.htm)

Comment: I do not want to pop them. I want that it will be done by the next function : printf in the example.

Comment: then you have to use vprintf versions of functions. see appropriate man pages

Comment: So take a look at [this guide](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_vprintf.htm)

Comment: Is a way exist without using vprintf ? Using another function with ...

Comment: NO such portable way

Comment: You can use macros. `#define test_va_arg(fmt, ...) fprintf(stdout, fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__)`

Comment: You cannot assume that arguments are on the stack. They might be in registers, or in both, or some other mechanism. It's not specified by the language.

Comment: @unwind Thanks, but how va_args know where are the arguments?

Comment: @flav That's an implementation detail. I would *expect* most typical implementations to always use the stack for varargs, but it's not required. So assuming that and trying to exploit it by "leaving things on the stack" is a bad idea, that's my point.

Answer (score 1):

After you comment, you must use [vprinf](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_vprintf.htm) like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

int test_va_arg(char * fmt, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    int c;

    va_start(args, fmt);
    c = vprintf(fmt, args);
    va_end(args);

    return (c);
}

int main(void) {
  int c;

  c = test_va_arg("test_va_arg : %d %d %d\n", 421, 847, 1003);
  printf("test_va_arg2 :%d\n", c);

  return (0);
}
```

---

After other comments you cna use a macro to do the job

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define test_va_arg(fmt, ...) fprintf(stdout, fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__)

int main(void)
{
    int c;

    c = test_va_arg("test_va_arg : %d %d %d\n", 421, 847, 1003);
    printf("test_va_arg2 :%d\n", c);

    return (0);
}
```